# How to read binary from pipe in PHP

Tags: php, stream, pipe, proc-open

I'm trying to create a PNG from an SVG using Inkscape. I'm using Linux. the command,

```
cat in.svg | inkscape -z /dev/stdin -w 800 -h 475 -e /dev/stderr 2> out.png
```

works fine, but I would rather not write the output files on the server.

My code is,

```
<?php
$svg_data = file_get_contents('in.svg');

$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
  2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr 
);

$pipes = array();

$process = proc_open("inkscape -z /dev/stdin -w 800 -h 475 -e /dev/stderr", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], $svg_data);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    $fil_data = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);  
    proc_close($process);
    file_put_contents("out.png", $fil_data);
}

?>
```

If I change the line,

```
$process = proc_open("inkscape -z /dev/stdin -w 800 -h 475 -e /dev/stderr", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

to

```
$process = proc_open("inkscape -z /dev/stdin -w 800 -h 475 -e out.png", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

The correct "out.png" is printed.

The current code writes a file, but the file is corrupted. It seems that it is corrupted from beginning to end, but it is about the right size.

I want the data (out.png) in $fil_data, but I don't want to read it from the disk drive.

Why is out.png corrupted, and how can I make the correct conversion without resorting to writing the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape was putting some messages to stderr before writing the file. The same thing happened on stdout. The problem was fixed by skipping past the messages. So the line,

```
$fil_data = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
```

was changed to,

```
$fil_data = stream_get_contents($pipes[2], -1, 150);
```

If there is a better way, I would like to see it.